# Very simple hash table inquisition

Tags: c, data-structures, hashtable

If the index for a hash table is calculated by using some integer value returned from a `hash()` function `% TABLE_SIZE`, doesn't that mean the only possibly index values are 0-9, since the range of the return value for the modulo operator is [0, 9]? I know this is really simple, but it's holding me back from understanding further hash table concepts.

Comment: Maybe I should be more specific - if getting a hash table index value by calling NUMBER % TABLE_SIZE, where NUMBER is always a positive integer, doesn't this always return a value between 0-9?

Comment: so what is your question here?

Comment: No. `x % y` can give values in the range 0 to y-1.

Comment: If x is always greater than y, and both are integers, how can it return something not in [0, 9]?

Comment: I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of the modulo operator. Simple example:150 % 100 = 50

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your understanding of `%` ([modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)) is incorrect. Specifically you seem to ignore the reason for the right-hand argument, and assume it's always a constant `10` which is simply false.

The expression `x % y` will return a value in the range 0 to (`y - 1`), inclusive (assuming both are unsigned).

Comment: I knew there was something I was missing, just couldn't put my finger on it.